# Use of undefined constant error on my project in PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have an Use of undefined constant error on my project. Here is the setup

The constant is;

```
define('VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN', '/views/admin');
```

and the file called from is

```
<?php
$mode = file_get_contents('../app/mode.php');

require '../app/' . $mode . '.php';

require VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN . '/index.php';
```

This is where the error occurs;

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN - assumed 'VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN'
```

The strange part of this is that it works fine on this file structure below

```
define('VIEW_ROOT', '/views');

<?php
$mode = file_get_contents('app/mode.php');

require 'app/' . $mode . '.php';

require VIEW_ROOT . '/index.php';
```

Any help here would be good :-)

This is the file structure

```
ROOT----
    |--admin
        |--index.php
    |--app
        |--development.php //Here are the contants define('VIEW_ROOT', '/views'); and define('VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN', '/views/admin');
        |--mode.php
        |--production.php
    |--views
        |--admin
            |--index.php
        |--index.php
    index.php
```

Comment: `$mode = file_get_contents('../app/mode.php');

require '../app/' . $mode . '.php';` that makes no sense.

Comment: This is just the mode of development or production environment

Comment: Not directly related, but a tip: Try to use the `__DIR__` Constant wherever possible, when dealing with including files. It always reflects the path to the directory, where the `__DIR__` is written. Thus, some constants you define are not necassary.

Comment: Yep tried it and still doesn't work. If you can't grasp the way the framework is setup then why do you bother answering or commenting. When i have an answer that works then i will accept it

Comment: *"When i have an answer that works then i will accept it"* - I quote: [*"Works Perfect Now – John Apr 4 '15 at 3:28"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442260/inserting-multiple-image-files-array-into-a-database#comment47052725_29442314) and you probably have others too.

Comment: Accepted Happy Now

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
<?php
require_once('/app/mode.php');   // this sets $mode = 'development' or similar
require_once('/app/' . $mode . '.php');   // this sets the constants
```

After that, the constant is defined and you can use it:

```
require_once(VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN . '/index.php');
```

I use require_once() in favor of require() to prevent files to be included more than once.

Comment: Yes app/mode.php just basically state whether development or production

Comment: Yeh but the problem still remains on `<?php require_once('../app/mode.php');`

Comment: In your file structure there is no mode.php file, so you can't find it.

Comment: sorry MODE is in the APP folder. The whole projects works great, but when i try to create the ADMIN folder in the structure above then it breaks

Comment: updated the file structure above, this is exactly correct

Comment: Ok, so you have a variable $mode which contains either 'development' or something else. /app/development.php defines both constants, VIEW_ROOT and VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN, and in all index.php you first require /app/development.php and then use the constants, correct?

Comment: I adapted my answer to match your new file structure

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher You know that you're doing all this in "good will" only. OP has a pretty bad track record when it comes to marking questions as solved.

Comment: How can your answer possibly work when `$mode = file_get_contents('../app/mode.php');` is only to switch the environments. The issue is with `$mode = file_get_contents('../app/mode.php');

require_once '../app/' . $mode . '.php';

require_once VIEW_ROOT_ADMIN . '/index.php';`

Comment: So /app/mode.php doesn't contain php code like the file extension suggests, but only a string "development"? file_get_contents() reads only the text content from a file, while require() executes the php code. So maybe this is the problem.